# Loading scripts before a function does not work in Chrome or Edge but it does in Firefox

Tags: javascript, promise

Due to a client's request I have had to create a banner whose html content and Javascript code are loaded directly from a database (the modal comes empty and through a rest service I retrieve the html that is stored in the table).

The case is that in the code that is loaded from the database, there are 2 scripts, which are hosted in different places.

The first, `createJS` does not give problems, but the second, hosted on another client server (because it does not want us to upload it to the same project from which it is loaded) does not always load well and because of this, the main script does not work correctly.

To solve this problem, in the script that comes in the DB I have added a promise that will be executed after the loading of said script. This method has worked for me correctly for Firefox, but for Chrome I still get the same problem.

I leave here the code with the important parts.

This is the code stored in the database:

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function initSol() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("XXXXXX");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", function(evt){handleFileLoad(evt,comp)});
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleFileLoad(evt, comp) {
    //some stuff    
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //some stuff
}
function loadJs(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let scrp = document.createElement('script');
    scrp.src = src;
    scrp.onload = () => resolve(scrp);
    document.body.append(scrp);
  });
}
var prom = loadJs("https://www.customerweb.com/resources/popup-withdadobeancode.js?12345678");
prom.then(
  scrp => initSol()
);  
var urlCheck = "check"; 
var urlClose = "close";
</script>
<div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00); width:910px; height:512px">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="910" height="512" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);"></canvas>
    <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:910px; height:512px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Error messages (only in Chrome and Edge, Firefox works fine):

> Uncaught TypeError: cjs.Bitmap is not a constructor  at popup-withdadobeancode.js?12345678:14  at popup-withdadobeancode.js?12345678:1288 VM72:2

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: AdobeAn.getComposition is not a function at initSol (:2:290) at :2:2103

In my opinion, I think the problem is loading the scripts. In Chrome, the code that requires the method `AdobeAn.getComposition` or `cjs.Bitmap` is executed before the script `popup-withdadobeancode.js` (which should be loaded first to avoid these errors), but I don't know how to make it run after loading.

Also, I can't load the script other than from the database as it doesn't depend on me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use onLoad event to wait until all ressources are loaded,also you should try appending the script before resolving the promise.

```
var prom = loadJs("https://www.customerweb.com/resources/popup-withdadobeancode.js?12345678");

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  prom.then(
  scrp => initSol()
);
});
```

Comment: When adding the code the error of  ``AdobeAn`` has disappeared but the ``cjs.Bitmap`` is still there

Comment: have you tried appending the script before resolving the promise ?

Comment: How? I'm testing now with Firefox and the banner doesn't load with this code anymore

Comment: document.body.append(scrp);
scrp.onload = () => resolve(scrp);

Comment: The same errors occur

Comment: Sorry , that all I have got :(